# Calculating the flux of the curl

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem, divergence-theorem

> Consider the sphere with radius $\sqrt{2}$ and centre the origin.  Let $S'$ be the portion of the sphere that is above the curve $C$
> (lies in the region $z \geq 1$) and has $C$ as a boundary. Evaluate the flux of $\nabla \times F$ through $S_0$. Specify which orientation you are using for $S'$.
>
> $$F = (z-y,0,y)$$
>
> (curve $x^2+y^2=1$ lying in the plane $z=1$).

So my thoughts are can we use the Divergence Theorem? If so when we use the $\text{curl} = \langle 1,1,1\rangle$?

Then when we apply the Divergence Theorem we can just say that the flux of this would be $0$? Or is this incorrect?

Comment: Please apply Stokes theorem

Comment: What is S0? You can use stoke's theorem. Or if you want to use divergence thorem then you meed another surface so that the whole surface is closed.

Comment: @Math Lover Stokes Theorem, as a piecewise was what I was thinking — one with the curve C and then the top of the surface - could you help parametrise the top surface

Comment: OK I am adding some details

Comment: @MathLover Thank you, much appreciated

Comment: Please do  not delete a question just after getting an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who provided that answer, and disrespectful to future readers who might benefit from that answer.

Comment: @MathLover sorry about that - the response was appreciated sorry about the deletion of the question 

Comment: ok @George, no problem

Answer (score 1):

Method1:

Parametrize the surface as $(\sqrt2 \cos\theta \sin \phi, \sqrt2 \sin\theta \sin \phi,\sqrt2 \cos \phi)$

Outward unit normal vector $\hat{n} = (\cos\theta \sin \phi, \sin\theta \sin \phi,\cos \phi)$

At $z = 1, \phi = \frac{\pi}{4}$

So use $0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{4}, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ to set up your double integral.

$\displaystyle \iint_R (\nabla \times \vec{F}) \cdot \hat{n} \ (\sqrt2)^2 \ d\phi \ d\theta$

Or Method 2

Take boundary C which is a circle of radius $1$ and parametrize as $r(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, 1), 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$.

$\displaystyle \int_C \vec{F} \cdot r'(t) \ dt$

Please make sure the orientation matches up for both integral.